# Created app need to transfer it over to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, environment

Ive created a weather app in vanilla js and want to use environment var's so that I can hide my api keys. I have found that env var's don't work in vanilla js, so I am looking to transfer it over to node.js and then ill be able to use env var.
Ive done lots of research but still struggling to know where to start. Any suggestions?

```
*node code*

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
// console.log(process.env);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("/Users/name/Desktop/Weather App/public/app.html");
});

// serve any HTML files located in /Users/name/Desktop/Weather App/public
app.use(express.static("/Users/name/Desktop/Weather App/public"));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("listening at 3000");
});
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Is something not working to your satisfaction with the code you have provided?  What do you need to know?

Comment: As a demonstration, create *app.js*:  `console.log(process.env.my_secret)`  then launch with `my_secret=abc123 node app.js`